# prove that $(\frac{n}{3})^n<n!<e\cdot(\frac{n}{2})^n$

Tags: inequality, factorial

prove that $$(\frac{n}{3})^n<n!<e\cdot(\frac{n}{2})^n$$

I tried to prove by the induction that $(\frac{n}{3})^n<n!$ and $n!<e\cdot(\frac{n}{2})^n$, but I failed

my assumption
$n^n<n!*3^n$

$$(n+1)^{n+1}<(n+1)*3^{n+1}$$
$$\frac{(n+1)^n}{9}<n!*3^{n-1}$$

Comment: You failed where exactly? How far you got?

Comment: You probably could use Stirling approximation for Log[n!]

Comment: and i don't understand why it doesn't work fo n=1

Comment: @Kacper for n = 1 you have $\frac{1}{3} < 1 < \frac{e}{2}$ which is true