# Proof by induction: $n^n\leq 3^nn!$ for any $n\geq1$

Tags: induction

I am struggling a lot trying to prove by indiction this inequality:

$$n^n\leq 3^nn! \text{ for any } n\geq1.$$

Could you please help me?
When I try to prove it for $n+1$, I find myself in this condition:
$$(n+1)^{n+1}\leq 3(n+1)3^nn!.$$

But I’m not sure how to continue from there.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). First cancel $n!$ on both sides. Then you have $1\le 3^n$, which should be easy to show.

Comment: You say $n!\leq 3^n n!$, but in your induction step you seem to be talking about $n^n\leq n!3^n$ instead. Which one is it?

Comment: @Arthur truly sorry! I ment $n^n$
I edited it now

Comment: I think, Arthur is right, and you need to show that $n^n\le 3^nn!$. Note that this is a *multiple duplicate*, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577015/prove-that-fracn3nne-cdot-fracn2n?noredirect=1), or better [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144176/factorial-inequality-problem-left-frac-n2-rightn-n-left-frac-n3-righ).

Comment: @DietrichBurde It doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. In the one you linked they explicitly asked to not solve it with induction. Instead I **need** to solve it with induction.
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Then take [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705520/proving-an-inequality-involving-factorials-fracn2n-ge-n-geq-frac?noredirect=1&lq=1), which **uses** induction. Did you look for other induction proofs already on this site?

Comment: @DietrichBurde i think that the induction step in that answer is wrong. He multiplies (n+1)*(n/2)^n instead of doing ((n+1)/2)^n+1

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think your link solves my issue but I'm struggling a bit understanding the demonstration. Isn't very straight forward but still thanks a lot!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I ment [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705520/proving-an-inequality-involving-factorials-fracn2n-ge-n-geq-frac?noredirect=1&lq=1). This demonstration looks wrong to me.

Comment: Multiplying an equation with $(n+1)$ is not yet wrong (in the beginning). But you have the choice to take the best answer (there are some more).